# Node not logging deeper subobject

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This may have been answered, but I did search.

In js file:

```
console.log({
  a: 1,
  b: { c: 1},
  d: [{e:1},{f:1}],
  g: [{h:[1,2,3]}]
});
```

This is what actually prints:

```
{ a: 1,
  b: { c: 1 },
  d: [ { e: 1 }, { f: 1 } ],
  g: [ { h: [Object] } ]
}
```

Notice 'h' value, can I print this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the docs for [util.inspect()](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors)

   It allows you to specify the depth to print at:
   `The default is to only recurse twice. To make it recurse indefinitely, pass in null for depth.`

   To use it, you could call `console.log(util.inspect(yourObj, true, null));`
2. [console.dir()](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_dir_obj) says it uses `util.inspect()`, but doesn't show parameters to modify the `inspect()` call, so it would probably only recurse twice, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for loop`  to iterate over it..

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: {c: 1},
    d: [{e: 1}, { f: 1}],
    g: [{  h: [1, 2, 3]}]
};

var data = obj.g[0].h ;

for(var i =0; i <data.length ; i++){
    console.log(data[i])
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RS5EW/)**

Comment: Why a jQuery answer when there is no mention of jQuery at all?

Comment: I don't want to manually loop over anything (the above was just an example, the object was arbitrary), I just want to print the ENTIRE object with console.log().

Comment: From the console you cannot print it that way

Answer (score 1):

I have used `JSON.stringify()` to achieve it, you can use parameters to determine the formatting.

As written above, `util.inspect()` also works.